# Very simple Javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

I need a super-readable version of this super simple inheritance in JavaScript. This is some auto-generated code, where I can't afford to be using external functions or libraries.

What I really want is, assuming Point3d "inherits" from Point, I want something like this:

```
function Point(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function Point3d(x,y,z) {
  Point(x, y);
  this.z = z;
}
```

Except it doesn't actually work:

```
var pt = new Point3d(230,30,11);
// but x and y are in global scope, they should be in pt.x and pt.y :(
```

One possible option, would in the code generation duplicate all the members -- but since Javascript is prototype based, I would imagine this is easy to do properly (if I actually knew Javascript)

Thanks

Comment: To set up the inheritance: `Point3d.prototype = Object.create( Point.prototype );`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply the `Point` constructor to the `Point3d` object using `.call()`.

```
function Point3d(x,y,z) {
  Point.call(this, x, y);
  this.z = z;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MSfu5/

The `.call` method sets the value of `this` in the function you're calling.

Here we're setting it to the new `Point 3d` object being constructed.

---

If there's anything on the `Point` prototype that `Point3d` should inherit, you can make the `Point3d.prototype` object an empty instance of `Point`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I didn't know about `call` this is exactly what I was hoping for

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object to begin with.

```
function Point(x,y) {
  return { x: x, y: y }
}

function Point3d(x,y,z) {
  var self=new Point(x, y);
  self.z=z;
  return self;
}
var pt = new Point3d(230,30,11);
```

Comment: -1 That inheritance model is broken. The "constructor" doesn't return the expected object, it returns some other object that **doesn't** inherit from Point (or Point3d). Use the answer from `am not i am`.

Comment: OP seemed to be asking about extending a data structure based on another, which is what I answered.  You're right tho, this doesn't create proper objects (I've been doing more perl lately)