# Javascript convert function declared as dict of functions to prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

What I'm trying to do is this:

My base code:

```
var Obj = function() {
    this.do = function() {};
    this.stop = function() {};
    this.kill = function() {};
};

Obj.prototype.load = function() {};
```

The desired conversion:

```
var ConvObject = function() { };
ConvObject.prototype = (typeof Obj == "function")? new Obj : Obj;
```

This example works (for the conversion part). In ConvObject, all methods of Obj are there. But in my case, I DO NOT want to execute the default constructor of Obj. I would prefer to avoid this. Indeed, I do not want to execute new Obj.

I've try differents ways to accomplish this. Here is the best answer I could find by now:

```
var getSizeOf = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
};

var ConvObject = function() { };
if ((typeof Obj == "function") && getSizeOf(Obj.prototype) == 0) {
  ConvObject.prototype = new Obj;
}
else {
  ConvObject.prototype = (typeof Obj == "function")? Obj.prototype : Obj;
}
```

This works when Obj looks like this:

```
var Obj = new function() {};
Obj.prototype.do = function() {};
Obj.prototype.stop = function() {};
Obj.prototype.kill = function() {};
Obj.prototype.load = function() {};
```

Or if it looks like this:

```
var Obj = function() {
    this.do = function() {};
    this.stop = function() {};
    this.kill = function() {};
    this.load = function() {};
};
```

But, this solution fails when I have the base code above. How can I avoid this call to the default constructor?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes but he doesn't want to call the constructor. Since the code of the constructor in that case is the only thing that adds the properties to the objects, it's only possible to get them by calling the constructor function.

Comment: You are more than right. I do have to call the constructor to have these functions. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (or its polyfill) to inherit directly from `Obj.prototype`.

To "inherit" instance methods from the `Obj` constructor, you should call it on every `ConvObject`: [Very simple Javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9073253/1048572). You would need to do this anyway when these methods are instance-specific, otherwise they should be on the prototype.

Comment: Indeed, this solution avoid the call to the constructor. Thanks for your answer but, Pointy makes me realize that what I want is impossible.

Comment: Oh, there's a solution for that as well. Though of course you will need to invoke the constructor, as Pointy said.